# Singleton, shared_ptr, raw pointer, or other pointer?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, shared-ptr

```
class GameBoy{

  public:
    GameBoy()
      :cart(new Cartridge()),
        mmu(new MMU(cart)),
        cpu(new CPU(mmu))
    {}

    void step(); //steps through one instruction
    const CPU::State &getCPUState() const noexcept;
    void loadROM(std::string fileName);

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<Cartridge> cart;
    std::shared_ptr<MMU> mmu;
    std::shared_ptr<CPU> cpu;

  };
```

I am writing a Game Boy emulator and this class is what the Qt GUI will interface with.  That is, for each frame drawn in the GUI, it will call GameBoy::step(). Obviously, it is not finished since I haven't started work on the GPU.

I am currently questioning this design since these 3 classes (Cartridge, CPU, MMU) will only be instantiated once.  Would a singleton be a better design than this, or would this current design be best?

If this one is best, should I stay with shared_ptr?  I have read that it should be used sparingly, but here, it seems to make sense since all 3 classes rely on each other.

Thank you very much!

EDIT:  People are asking me why I am using pointers at all.  As you can see from the init list, MMU needs a reference to the Cartridge and CPU needs a reference to the MMU.

The Cartridge will be used by GameBoy::loadROM() and most MMU methods. I agree the MMU may not need to be owned by the GameBoy, but it will be shared shared between the CPU and GPU (I think).

In the example below, is there a better alternative to the cart shared pointer?

Example usage between classes:

```
byte MMU::readByte(word address) {
            ....
            value = cart->readROM(address);
            ....
        }

void GameBoy::loadROM(std::string fileName){
            cart->loadROM(fileName);
}
```

EDIT 2: Thanks everyone!  I have one final question.  If the GPU and CPU both use the MMU and the GameBoy uses both the GPU and CPU, which design is better:

```
class GameBoy{

public:
GameBoy()
 : CPU(&mmu), gpu(&mmu)
...

private:
MMU mmu;  //never used by GameBoy
CPU cpu;  //CPU and GPU used in GameBoy
GPU gpu;

};

class CPU{
...

private:
MMU *mmu;
};

class GPU{

...

private:
MMU *mmu;

};
```

or:

```
class GameBoy{

public:
GameBoy()
 : CPU(), gpu(&cpu.getMMU())
...

private:
CPU cpu; //CPU and GPU used in GameBoy
GPU gpu;

};

class CPU{
...

private:
MMU mmu;  //arbitrarily chosen owner.  GPU could have been the owner
};

class GPU{

...

private:
MMU *mmu;

};
```

I like the first one a bit better since it seems more consistent, but GameBoy never uses the MMU.

Comment: why the shared pointers?

Comment: I should have put this in my description, but as you can see from the init list, the MMU needs a pointer to the Cartridge and the CPU needs a pointer to the MMU.  Is there a better way of doing this with statically allocated objects?

Comment: does the Gameboy class use all three ?

Comment: See my latest edit.  It was intuitive for me to think that the GameBoy owns the CPU, GPU, Cartirdge and MMU and some of these devices are shared amongst each other, as per this design: https://github.com/drhelius/Gearboy/blob/master/src/GearboyCore.h

Comment: generally , if its not using it then it shouldn't own it

Comment: They are used. As of now, for example, the cart object is used both by the GameBoy and the MMU objects.  See edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am currently questioning this design since these 3 classes
>   (Cartridge, CPU, MMU) will only be instantiated once.

No user would ever want to, say, watch their friend play a game? Streaming the commands and emulating them on the host is much more bandwidth-efficient than streaming a video. And nobody, ever, would want to do that "link mode" thing with a friend. Never ever, sir.

To wit, the idea that this is some kind of cornerstone of your application, as would actually justify a Singleton, is plain wrong. Your current design and features do not call for more than this, but there is *absolutely no reason whatsoever* to lock yourself in. Secondly, *even if* they could only be instantiated once, ever, this could effectively be enforced by some `private` access controls and would absolutely not require global state.

The short is, Singletons are one of the worst ideas in modern programming. Don't ever use one.

> If this one is best, should I stay with shared_ptr? I have read that
>   it should be used sparingly, but here, it seems to make sense since
>   all 3 classes rely on each other.

Er, no. Why use a pointer at all? Just have them as member variables directly. A cross-class dependency is no reason to use `shared_ptr`, just use a T*.

Comment: My plan is to actually incorporate online play.  Now, initially, I thought of not needing another instance of GameBoy, and just pass packets back and forth without any abstraction.  Now I realize I'll use a GameBoy object to represent the second player.  This was short sighted.

Based on my recent edit, if 2 objects (in this case the GameBoy and the MMU) share an object (the Cartridge), use a raw pointer?  Is there ever a reason to use shared_ptr?

Comment: @DanB91: `shared_ptr` is only for sharing *ownership*. Merely needing to refer to an object does not justify the use of `shared_ptr`. In this case, the GameBoy object can own the mmu/cart/cpu with no problems, so there is no reason to use shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little reason to use a Singleton other than to make a Global object/variable a bit more fancy.  If you find a good design to avoid globals, its an easy bet that its better than a Singleton.

Some (debatable) exceptions is a logger class or access to resources that may be inherently global in a system, like shared memory.

As far as the use of shared_ptr versus unique_ptr. Stick with a unique_ptr unless you have a very good reason to need a shared_ptr. Here they will be functionally equivalent but unique_ptr clearly indicates that `Gameboy` class owns the three objects with one instance each.  Also as noted in some of the other answers, you can avoid pointers entirely, but there are benefits to using them as well as not.

> I should have put this in my description, but as you can see from the init list, the MMU needs a pointer to the Cartridge and the CPU needs a pointer to the MMU. Is there a better way of doing this with statically allocated objects?

One way is to ditch the init list since your constructor is a bit more complicated and handle the order explicitly.

```
GameBoy()
  :cart(nullptr),
    mmu(nullptr),
    cpu(nullptr)
{
    cart = new Cartrige();
    mmu = new MMU(cart);
    cpu = new CPU(mmu);
}
```

Comment: I don't get the last part. Members are initialized in the order of declaration, so it's really the same thing in regards to order.

Comment: True, but this method is safe because if you separate the declaration (.h) and definition (.cpp) its easy to disturb the order in future modifications.  Better to be explicit in this case.

Comment: That's what comments are for imo. Comment the group of declarations and say not to change the order and why.

Comment: Well, just personal preference and experience here. Depending on how big the team is you work on and how long the code lasts. Comments can sometimes be, well, unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

A good design will let you run multiple emulations simultaneously, even if the requirement never occurs in practice.

I think you have two options, depending how the dependencies work. If mmu needs a cartridge, why not make cartridge a member of mmu? And mmu a member of cpu. Or if you want to keep them all accessible inside gameboy, I assume all three will live as long as gameboy. Store them as unique_ptr or full-members (without pointer) inside gameboy, pass them to the subclasses by regular pointer, and then they will be deleted when gameboy is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Change is constant, you should be confident that a time will come when you will want to change your code. That means if your current design does not **require** a singleton then there is no reason to limit yourself to that. The current implementation allows for more extensibility.

As for `shared_ptr`, you use that when you need multiple pointers to the **same** , **shared** , instance. For example lets say you have 3 classes `A` , `B` and `C`. `B` and `C` both have a pointer to an instance of `A` , one instance shared between `B` and `C` and thus should only be deleted after **both** `B` and `C` are deleted. In that example you should use a `shared_ptr`. otherwise you should use `unique_ptr`. Therefore you should not be using `shared_ptr`. Actually if `cart`, `mmu` and `cpu` are concrete classes ,not interfaces / base classes, you shouldn't use any sort of pointers.

EDIT:

why does the `GameBoy` class need instances of  `Cartridge` , `MMU` and `CPU` ? why not just a `CPU` that creates its own `MMU` that creates its own `Cartridge` ?

Comment: I could do that.  But, GameBoy needs a loadROM, method. I was thinking it was a bit more intuitive to say cart->loadROM() than mmu->loadROM().  But, maybe the elimination of pointers is better than making the code very slightly more intuitive. 

Let's say the MMU needs to be shared between the CPU and GPU and CPU owns a full MMU object. Is it only then I should make the MMU a pointer in CPU (and in GPU)?

Comment: You may use getCart()->loadROM(), so it is easier to change getCard() to return getMMU()->getCart() or cart depending where cart is.